# Replication not updating XML Schema collection

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication

So the problem I'm facing is that replication from our Main instance to our Data Warehouse instance is failing because it isn't picking up XML schema updates. Thus, when it tries to bulk copy the data from the Main table that utilizes it, it fails because XML validation fails due to the XMLSchemaCollection not containing any of the updates.

The behavior that we've observed in the last couple months is that if the XML schema is new, then replication picks it up. However, from that point forward, it ignores it. This smells like a deficiency in the way it detects updates. But I'm hoping that someone else has figure this out.

Comment: You might want to try dba.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Lots of missing information here.  What type of replication are you using?  How do you perform the XML schema updates?

Comment: I believe it is snapshot, but I'll have to verify that. The XML schema update is done by script. The script unbinds the collection from the column, then drops the collection and rebuilds it (we're adding a schema to the old collection), the rebinds it to the column.

Comment: @BrandonWilliams, I just looked at the publications for the main database and it appears to be transactional